# Can I connect 2 laptops one asus another acer together so they can share their ram

Tags: laptop, memory, cluster

So the issue is I want to run a R code estimating R0 values for a city to find this I run bootstrap simulation of 11000, for the city the code stops as I don't have the required memory in a single laptop it requires around 5gb and I have a laptop which has 4gb but free memory is around 1.4gb and I require another 1.3gb , and I also have an older laptop which also has 1.4 gb free so the question is there a way that I can use both laptops together to run the code

Comment: Go buy 8GB and/or run with extra Virtual memory

Comment: It sounds like you have a 32-bit operating system. Cluster computing is possible but requires orchestrating at a considerably higher level than trying to strap 2 under-performing laptops together. Get a 64-bit OS & more RAM.

Comment: So I have a 64 bit OS  will check virtual memory an addition one is windows 7 and other is windows 10

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can reuse ram in another computer. The problem is that usually by the time one has upgraded, the type of ram/ slots change so it may not be usable. And even if it fits, it speed may be clocked slower than the ram that comes with your new computer and causing it to retard overall performance.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as asked.